# IE9 resubmitting form after 302 - possibly due to recursive setTimeout() call

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, settimeout, form-submit

I'm seeing the following in IE9

1. Javascript submits form via .submit()
2. Server returns 302 on success
3. IE does GET on redirected URL
4. IE re-submits form via .submit()

The submit happens inside a function that recursively calls itself via setTimeout, which I think might be the culprit. But I don't see any way, logically, that the submit could happen twice. Here's the function:

```
function callback() {
    "use strict";

    var poll_timeout, // setting a var in case we need to kill the timeout mid count
        poll_counter = 0, // start a counter
        max_polls = 10; // set a max count

    function doPoll() {
        if (poll_counter < max_polls) { // make sure we're not above the count
            poll_counter++; // increment the counter
            $.post("/someUrl", function (success) {
                // ajax it
                if (success) {
                    $("form#checkout").off('submit', Store.cancel_submit)
                    $('form#checkout').submit();
                } else {
                    // do it again
                    poll_timeout = setTimeout(doPoll,10000);

                }
            });
        }
    }
    doPoll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with jQuery's `$.post` if that's not the same as `$.ajax`, but I would do this to prevent the poll_timeout from running again when we've had success:

```
if (success) {
    clearTimeout(poll_timeout);
    $("form#checkout").off('submit', Store.cancel_submit)
    $('form#checkout').submit();
} else {
    // do it again
    poll_timeout = setTimeout(doPoll,10000);
}
```